# What is the difference between jquery and jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What is the difference between jQuery and jQuery UI? Are they both different frameworks? Is jQuery library needed to work jquery UI or both works standalone? what is difference between any jQuery tab plugin and jQuery UI Tab? which is better to use?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

jQuery is the core library. jQueryUI is built on top of it. If you use jQueryUI, you must also include jQuery.

jQuery Tabs preceded jQueryUI library. jQueryUI Tabs is based on jQuery Tabs. The current version of jQuery Tabs is [Tabs 3](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs_3/). If I recall correctly (I vaguely remember looking through the source code about a year ago), Tabs 3 is very similar to what's in jQueryUI. The jQueryUI version, of course, respects the Themeroller themes.

I used jQueryUI in one project. It has some nice features, but there are few widgets and it seems to be advancing at a glacial pace (seems like the same six widgets have been there for over a year). Maybe it'll get a second wind. If I recall, one of the things that bothered me is that in many of the widgets, there was no visible difference between the hover state and the click state.

So I would not recommend jQueryUI at this time for its widgets. You may want it for the effects and the draggable/dropable interactions handling.

The widgets in Google's Closure library and the widgets in ExtJS seem more useful, in my opinion.

Comment: you mean like other people are making plugins for jquery , jquery team itself making jquery plugins and named it as "jQuery UI". am i right?

Comment: The jQuery team works on jQuery. jQueryUI was, I believe, an attempt at an official effects, theming, and widget library.

Answer (score 6):

Just browse to the [jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/home) and read:

> **jQuery UI** provides abstractions for
>   low-level interaction and animation,
>   advanced effects and high-level,
>   themeable widgets, **built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library**, that you
>   can use to build highly interactive
>   web applications.

Comment: i have read already but if we have for something to at both placeshttp://plugins.jquery.com/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/ like Tab , Accordion etc.

Answer (score 2):

- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is built on top of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It offers cool user interface enhancements.
- *@2nd question* > Use what you like, end-user- and developer-interface-wise.

Comment: my question is if we have two option for any requirement one is any jquery plugin and second is jquery UI solution then what will be better to use?

Comment: the more javascript you need to include, the more the client needs to download. if a simple jquery plugin fulfills the need, go with it.

Comment: True, but both jQuery and jQuery UI are hosted at googleapis. If you use that version, it's likely to already be in the browser cache and not downloaded.

Comment: Also jQuery UI's CSS and all images are hosted in the google apis as well: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

You'll also discover that you can't live without jQuery. It's a crucial piece to almost any web application. And since it's footprint is so small you can get away with including on most if not all pages.

jQuery UI however is heavier with css and images. It can also be difficult to get the style to work with existing applications. I find myself using jQuery UI components some of the time and jQuery nearly all the time.

Comment: Can't live without jQuery unless you use moo, yui, dojo, prototype.js, glow, or closure. :-)

Comment: Nosredna: watch out, the SO jQuery Fanboy Mafia will put a pony's head in your bed. It's such a hassle getting the bloodstains out of the duvet.

Comment: I've been using jQuery for years, but I guess you're right--I'm clearly lacking in zealotry and should pay dearly for it.

Comment: OK, so "can't live without" is overstated. The question however was comparing jQuery and jQueryUI. It had nothing to do with comparing it with other JS frameworks. If you're really offended, feel free to replace jQuery with your favorite own JS framework de jure.

Oh, and the pony's head is on its way.