# JQuery Tooltip with Primefaces: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to use a jQuery Tooltip in a JSF application where I use Primefaces (so, jQuery is automatically loaded by Primefaces), but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

I use the tooltip function in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

        //jQuery Tooltip
         $( document ).tooltip();
    });

    </script>
```

**UPDATE**

If I "manual" include jquery-ui it works:

```
<h:outputScript name="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
```

---

PF 6.0 (with jQuery v1.11.3)
WildFly 10

Comment: Have you imported the right file? would it be possible to have your HTML aswell

Comment: Check the way you include the tooltip JS code. It does not recognise the function. It may be that the URL tot eh JS file which has the tooltip function in it is not correct. We can only guess because we do not have enough info in your post.

Comment: I use primefaces, so the jQuery and jQuery ui should be already be included (and they are, I can use jQuery functions within my *.xhtml Files), but for some reasons the function "tooltip" cannot be found

Comment: this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857324/how-to-include-jquery-library-for-jsf-with-primefaces-ui

Comment: Thx, I have already tried it without success (I have some PF tags in my xhtml page, so jQuery should really be loaded)

Comment: why can't you use primefaces [tooltips](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml)?

Comment: I need to set a tooltip for a <td>-element

Comment: have you try just adding the `title` property to your <td> element , that should work

Comment: Yes, it works. But then I want to use the jQuery Tooltip to show the tooltip (and not the browser default tooltip)

Comment: then use the [global tooltip](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipGlobal.xhtml) in addition to the `title` property

Comment: I didn't know it, thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tooltip is part of jquery ui, but not of jquery (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775990/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-jquery-ui) for differences). PrimeFaces uses jQuery, but only parts of jquery ui. tooltip is not part of it. So you can't use tooltip with PrimeFaces only. You have to load it yourself like you did in your question. But be careful that you choose a jquery ui version that is compatible with PrimeFaces' jquery version.